# Call App from URL using window.location.replace in Android6

Tags: javascript, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I launch my Android App from a Web Page from the Android Internet Brownser using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY">
   <form id="userform" method="POST" action="myaction" onsubmit="btngra.disabled = true; return true;">
      <input type="hidden" id="buttonlaunch" class="boton" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Go&nbsp;&nbsp;" onClick="window.location.replace('myapp://whatever');">
      <input type="submit" class="boton" name="btngra" id="btngra" value=" &nbsp;&nbsp;Grabar&nbsp;&nbsp; ">
   </form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById('buttonlaunch').click();
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The problem is that from Android 6 this stopped working. Looks like "window.location.replace" does not accept the URL of the APP. Does anybody now how to make it work in Android 6?

Thanks in advance,

Ivan.

Comment: Try with assign. If you are fine have the url in the history.

onClick="window.location.assign('myapp://whatever');"

Comment: Hi Karpak, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately neither works wit assign :(. Putting a link with href makes the element "clickable" and opens the App but it is not the same behaviour than the code I wrote.